# Identical string literals are considered equal?

Tags: c

I have written the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    if("ddd" == "ddd")
        printf("equal");
    else
        printf("not equal");
}
```

The output is "equal", but according to me, the output should be "not equal" because the string literals are stored in the literal pool or some read only memory (I guess it depends on OS), so both strings should have two different addresses as they are stored at different addresses in memory.

Previously, I have done the same type of example (one year back), and that time the output was "not equal". Now, could anyone tell me, is this due to a change in the C standard, or am I missing something?

Comment: For comparing string use `strcmp()`.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents the compiler from optimizing by using the same address , as the string literals here are const.

Comment: Why would somebody ever do something like this?

Comment: @AlexisKing This question asks why it's equal, not the other way. So technically, not a duplicate in my opinion, although the same answer can answer both questions.

Comment: @YuHao The answers on that question do indeed answer this question, mentioning that compilers *may* produce code that results in equality, but it's not required one way or the other by the C standard.

Comment: @AlexisKing Like [this Meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/1009479) says, *many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates.* After all, this question asks why it's equal, and the other question asks why it's not equal. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @YuHao I would argue that the two questions are effectively the same thing, but I suppose that's subjective. They're both about string literal reference equality, which is fairly specific as-is.

Comment: @AlexisKing, i as a user first of all, search for exact requirements. i already knew that "a" != "a" so i didn't searched for that thread. 
for example - u alread know that office is closed on sunday . will u go and check whether it is open or not?

Comment: ok, thank you all . so i finally concluded that result may vary from compiler to compiler , as compiler may keep only 1 copy in literal pool if strings are same  OR it may keep same string at 2 different location. correct me if i m wrong.

Answer (score 6):

It's unspecified for string literals with the same content to have the same address or not. So the output of your program could be `equal` or it could be `not equal`, your compiler happens to put them in the same place.

> #### C11 6.4.5 String literals
>
> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
> appropriate values.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, what you do in that condition is a *comparison between pointers* (use `strcmp` to compare *C strings*).

So, I think it is a compiler *translation/optimization* that "maps" identical literals at the same location in the memory.

**EDIT 1:**

The following sample confirms what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* a = "ddd";
char* b = "ddd";
char* c = "ddd";

int main() {
    printf ("a => %p\nb => %p\nc => %p\n", a, b, c);
}
```

The previous program, compiled with `gcc` using `-O0` and executed will print:

```
a => 0x40060c
b => 0x40060c
c => 0x40060c
```

I don't know how other compilers will treat the same situation.

Comment: , i have already removed optimisation (cc -O0 prog.c , i guess there is still some optimization there) then also compiler is storing same string literals in one memory location only. thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you're comparing two character values (which are not pointers), it is a numeric comparison.

But when you're comparing two string, Base address of strings are compared.If supposed compilers treats as both string are in same location ,then o/p is equal.Otherwise Not.

What you are comparing the two memory addresses for the different strings, which are stored in different locations.so,Not equal.

Even it is read only memory,you are used this for comparison only.You are not modify or not write anything.